# Rails model query with many optional params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A user wants to search by an attribute and/or order the results. Here are some example requests

```
/posts?order=DESC&title=cooking
/posts?order=ASC
/posts?title=cooking
```

How can I conditionally chain such options to form a query?

So far I have a very ugly method that will quickly become difficult to maintain.

```
  def index
    common = Hash.new
    common["user_id"] = current_user.id

    if params[:order] && params[:title]

      @vacancies = Post.where(common)
                          .where("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", params[:title])
                          .order("title #{params[:order]}")

    elsif params[:order] && !params[:title]

      @vacancies = Post.where(common)
                          .order("title #{params[:order]}")

    elsif params[:title] && !params[:order]

      @vacancies = Post.where(common)
                          .where("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", params[:title])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that query methods like `where` and `order` are meant to be chained. What you want to do is start with a base query (like `Post.where(common)`, which you use in all cases) and then conditionally chain other methods:

```
def index
  common = Hash.new
  common["user_id"] = current_user.id

  @vacancies = Post.where(common)

  if params[:order]
    @vacancies = @vacancies.order(title: params[:order].to_sym)
  end

  if params[:title]
    @vacancies = @vacancies.where("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", params[:title])
  end
end
```

P.S. Your original code had `.order("title #{params[:order]}")`. This is very dangerous, since it opens you up to SQL injection attacks. As a rule of thumb *never* use string concatenation (`#{...}`) with a value you get from the end user when you're going to pass the result to the database. Accordingly, I've changed it to `.order(title: params[:order])`. Rails will use this hash to construct a secure query so you don't have to worry about injection attacks.

You can read more about SQL injection attacks in Rails in the official [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection).

Comment: Excellent answer. One small thing, had to convert 'order' to symbol to get this working: `params[:order].to_sym`. Error said only :asc and :desc were accepted directions.